# Dynamically changing text color over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to change the color of text to white when the image is "dark" and black when the image is "light"?

I need this because my background is pulled from flickr and I can't guarantee what it'll be!

[Here is what i've got so far](http://georgetaylor.co.nf/test/)

Comment: Added link.

fiddle doesn't work due to libraries used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346405/automatically-contrasting-text-color-based-on-background-image-color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762864/image-dark-light-detection-client-sided-script

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decide font color in white or black depending on background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942878/how-to-decide-font-color-in-white-or-black-depending-on-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the "canvas" tag with a simple function located here -> http://jsfiddle.net/s7Wx2/

source: [Image Dark/Light Detection Client Sided Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762864/image-dark-light-detection-client-sided-script)

```
getImageLightness("image.jpg",function(brightness){
    console.log(brightness);
});
```